# How go to other drive on XP (VirtualBox)

Tags: cmd, virtualbox

I want to go to drive E:\ into cmd. Do you know how can I do it?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for `cd` command. Try this:

> cd /d E:

**On a side note:-**

`cd` stands for Change Directory

Comment: `cd` has the paramter `/d`to change the drive too.

Comment: @Stephan:- missed that! Updated my answer. Thanks for the update!

Comment: I didn't know about option `/d`. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can just type the name of the drive and it'll `cd` into it.

In your case, just type:

```
E:
```

and hit Enter.

Answer (score 0):

`E:` is a network drive.

You may need to apply `username and password`, which can be done with the `net use` command.

Comment: It's a shared drive on a network.  You can see the icon shows that.

Comment: This screen is from XP installed on VirtualBox. I share C:\ drive from my computer (Win7) to virtual XP. In this case XP read shared folder as netdrive.

Comment: The connection from the VM goes through a virtual network using your NIC inside the computer.  It really is a network drive.

Comment: Ok. Anyway, auth is not required. Command `cd /d E:` is sufficient.